# How can I use Powershell to compare two CSV files, then update the one of the CSV files with results of comparison

Tags: powershell, csv

I would like to compare two CSV files a 'master' and 'input', then update the 'master' file so it contains the differences

the 'master' file will initially contain some data... like this:

```
A,B,C
5,9,cat
1,2,dog
2,8,rabbit
8,8,mouse
6,2,duck
```

The 'input' file may have entries from the master file will need to be **UPDATED**, have **NO CHANGE** or have been **ADDED**:

```
A,B,C
1,2,otter
8,8,mouse
5,3,tiger
```

Now, master file and input file are compared and here are the results:

***UPDATED***

There is a difference between master and input for 1,2
master file contains : 1,2,***dog*** input file contains 1,2,***otter***, an update to the master file will be required

***NO CHANGE***

The master *AND* input file contain: 8,8,mouse, so nothing is done

***ADDED***

The input file contains a new entry **5,3,tiger**, so the master file will be appended with that new data

**RESULTING MASTER FILE**

```
A,B,C
5,9,cat
1,2,otter
2,8,rabbit
8,8,mouse
6,2,duck
5,3,tiger
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
$apples = Get-Content $Input
$oranges = Get-Content $Master

# this will generate the file that contains ONLY the CHANGED or new entries that must be recorded
Compare-Object $apples $oranges -PassThru | Where-Object{ $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } | Out-File $OutFile

# this will generate the file that contains the old entries that need to be replaced with the new ones
Compare-Object $apples $oranges -PassThru | Where-Object{ $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } | Out-File $FixUp
```

Here is where I am stuck... I can get the 'fixup' and the 'old' entries... but I don't know how to use them to update the master file ?

I was thinking of looping through the files... but then thought... How do I correlate the master to the fix up changes:

```
    $csv = Import-Csv $FixUp
    #This works fine
    for($i = 0; $i -lt @($csv).Length; $i++){

        #$find = how do i get old csv value from master file ???
        #$replace = $csv
        #(Get-Content $file).replace($find, $replace) | Set-Content $file            
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm am I wrong - your "input file" looks exactly like your desired "result file"? Could you explain a little more detailed what you expect? You may update your question with some more example data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf - it starts out comparing the 'master' with the input file.  The 'master' doesn't have the data from the input file when the script starts... but when the script is done it will

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf  - I should also add, the master file ALSO changes 1,2,3 to 1,2,4

Comment: Now you described with some more words the same situation. The fact is - at least with the example data you provided so far - that you end up, with the complete "input file". Is there a case thinkable, where you not use the entries from the "input file"?

Comment: I agree with Olaf - as per your explanation and sample data, output file = input file. I suggest you update your sample data to so that the master file contains data that isn't in the input file. Also, you need to make it clear that the _first two_ data items are what matters (the key) and the third data item is an 'attribute' which is updated.

Comment: Regardless of that I'd recommend to treat CSV files as such if they are valid. So instead of using `Get-Content` you should use `Import-Csv` to be able to seelect the proper attributes for your comparison.

Comment: The point of the question is the master file will be updated with data from the input file.  That is why I am calling it the 'master' file.  The input file simply changes or adds data to the master file.  So in the example data, the master file contains an entry 1,2,3.  The input file changes the 3 to a 4.  so the final record in the master file is 1,2,4.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf and https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690193/nick-mcdermaid - I have updated the question with data that is easier to see where the changes occur

Comment: See my updated answer, please. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you treat your input data as CSV data you can choose what atttributes `Compare-Object` should use for the comparison.

```
$Apples = @'
A,B,C
5,9,cat
1,2,dog
2,8,rabbit
8,8,mouse
6,2,duck
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Csv
$Oranges = @'
A,B,C
1,2,otter
8,8,mouse
5,3,tiger
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Csv

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Oranges -DifferenceObject $Apples -Property A, B -IncludeEqual -PassThru
```

That will end up in the result:

```
A B C      SideIndicator
- - -      -------------
1 2 otter  ==
8 8 mouse  ==
5 9 cat    =>
2 8 rabbit =>
6 2 duck   =>
5 3 tiger  <=
```

Comment: thanks... but how can the row of the end result 1,2,4 in Oranges be  ==   the original row in Apples is 1,2,3 ... NOT 1,2,4

Comment: Because it starts with "1,2" and that's what is specified for the comparison `-Property A,B`. That's what we asked for you. What is your criteria for the comparison? You may (re-)read the help for `Compare-Object` to understand how it works and to set your expectations. ;-)

Comment: I updated the code snippet in my answer. The code (the comparison) stays actually the same.

Comment: Thanks Olaf... sorry for the confusion at first...  :-)